# Android custom listView click - how to call an intent to another activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

Some one help please. I'm trying to create an app with a custom list view which has text view and image view. the list items are filtered and on clicking on the list item it should open up an associated activity. However the app crashes when i click on an item giving message,"thread exiting with uncaught exception". Here are my codes.

> main.java

```
package com.example.lenovo.filterapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;

    String[] names = {"Lionel Messi","Christiano Ronaldo","Neymar JNR","Luis Suarez"};
    int[] images ={R.drawable.badge,R.drawable.bucky,R.drawable.dentala,R.drawable.house};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        //Adapter
        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this,getPlayers());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });

        final HashMap<String, Class> hashMap=new HashMap<String, Class>();


        hashMap.put("Lionel Messi",Lionel.class);
        hashMap.put("Christiano Ronaldo",Christiano.class);
        hashMap.put("Neymar JNR",Neymar.class);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String openClass = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        hashMap.get(openClass));
                startActivity(myIntent1);
            }

        });

    }

    private ArrayList<Player> getPlayers(){
        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        Player p;

        for (int i = 0;i<names.length;i++){
            p = new Player(names[i],images[i]);
            players.add(p);
        }
        return players;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> Adapter.java

package com.example.lenovo.filterapp;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by LENOVO on 2/6/2016.
 */
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Player> players;
    CustomFilter filter;
    ArrayList<Player> filterList;

    public Adapter(Context c, ArrayList<Player> players) {
        this.c = c;
        this.players = players;
        this.filterList = players;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return players.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return players.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return players.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customrow,null);
        }

        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buckysTextView);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alisImageView);

        //Set data to them
        nameTxt.setText(players.get(position).getName());
        img.setImageResource(players.get(position).getImg());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if(filter == null){
            filter = new CustomFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    //Inner Class
    class CustomFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
                //Constraint to Upper
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                ArrayList<Player> filters = new ArrayList<Player>();

                //get specific Items
                for (int i =0;i<filterList.size();i++){

                    if(filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        Player p = new Player(filterList.get(i).getName(),filterList.get(i).getImg());

                        filters.add(p);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filters.size();
                results.values = filters;
            }
            else {
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            players = (ArrayList<Player>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

> Player.java

package com.example.lenovo.filterapp;

```
/**
 * Created by LENOVO on 2/6/2016.
 */
public class Player {

    private  String name;
    private int img;

    public Player(String name, int img) {
        this.name = name;
        this.img  = img;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            >
            <SearchView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:queryHint="search...." />


            <ListView

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

> manifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lenovo.filterapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lenovo.filterapp.Lionel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lionel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lenovo.filterapp.Christiano"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_christiano"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lenovo.filterapp.Neymar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_neymar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

finding the reason behind my crash is really hard. What might be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you debug and check if `hashMap.get(openClass)` returns the correct class name..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the focus of the components in your custom list view.

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

A workaround is as I have done in my application - you can try to replace the onItemClickListener with the onItemTouchListener like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

//we need this to identify the gesture of the goalsRecyclerView touch
final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
});

lv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))//only if clicked on an existing child and not swiping
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    return true;//transfer the touch event to the recyclerView
                }
                return false;//ignore the event
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
            }
            });
}
```

This works just fine for my scenarios with customListViews

Comment: thanks but android studio cannot resolve method addOnItemTouchListener. anything i can do about it?

Comment: This method is for RecyclerView - this is a better choise because it handles the reusage of the next renderred item with the last hidden one. The listener is RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener. You can try to replace your listView with a RecyclerView and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on list click

```
String openClass = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

instead of

```
String openClass = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
```